# Visual Studio 2013 - Entity Framework - Update Wizard not responding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, edmx

I'm trying to refresh my EDMX through the Update Wizard, I've waited around 30 mins but nothing happens and it stops responding. I only have around 23 tables, which shouldn't be too much.

[image: Update Wizard stays unresponsive after 30 mins of waiting]

I've tried these and none are working:

- Restart VS 2013.
- Tried on VS 2012.
- Restart Windows.
- Add a data server connection through the Servers tab in VS.

And now I'm clueless on what to do. I'm aware that I can manually update the EDMX definition through Notepad, but that's too tedious to do everytime. Any hints on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Can you try to do the same after disabling any addins?

Comment: What database your default connection string points to?

Comment: I found that you can run into this issue if there's a connection issue from your VS to the designated connection string. In my case, it was my home ISP that blocks connection to SQL ports. I changed my internet connection and it works.

Comment: Setting the compatibility level to 110 might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700540/update-wizard-not-responding

Answer (score 2):

I think a clean repair of Visual Studio 2013 will fix your issue. I had the same problem, and a clean repair fixed it for me. Btw, I see this question is old, you have probably fixed it, which I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a bit too late but what I did in order to fix this was to delete the database being used by the EF and then recreate it using generated scripts. It may not be the best solution but it kinda works (since my only issue is that the update wizard is not responding and my database has no values at all this one is ok for me), use this only as a last resort.